# add xml string or text in soap body without using documentFactory? is it possible?

Tags: java, xml, soap

String payload = "<GetAccountList xmlns='http://example.com'><AccountId>wadjqweh-38ur2f</AccountId></GetAccountList>";

lets say this is may string payload and want to add it inside soap body element, I dont see any options!!

Note: I have used this method. it is working but giving me some problem while building my application.

```
private static Document convertStringToDocument(String xmlStr) {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder;
    try {
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlStr)));
        return doc;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```